# Added a page to my wordpress site and I cannot access it using Filezilla

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, filezilla

I have made a form in a wordpress page with an action linking to a PHP-file.

The code is this:

```
<form name="logind" method="post" action="tjeklogin.php">
```

However, when I try to access the file from my website it can't find it. I'm using Filezilla as my FTP-client but I have no idea where to place the PHP-file to make it link to my form.

When I click the submit button the URL becomes: http://indreoesterbro.bysileha.com/log-ind/tjeklogin.php and I can't find the page called "log-ind" in my Filezilla.

I hope somebody can help. Don't hesitate to ask any questions.

Comment: you'd have to know what your site's document root is, and how the url "directories" below that document root (`/log-ind/....`) relate to that document root. we can't help you with that. that's something you'll have to find in your server's configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a path relative url for your action. So it's taking the current page, `http://indreoesterbro.bysileha.com/log-ind/`, and appending the action to the end. You can't find the `log-ind` url because it doesn't exist as a file, it's being rewritten to the index.php.

What you probably want is `action="/tjeklogin.php"`. The `/` before it means the link is relative to the web root, `http://indreoesterbro.bysileha.com/`. So your link would then resolve as `http://indreoesterbro.bysileha.com/tjeklogin.php`.